# OnFontChange method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have my control MyLabel and when I change the Font Size must perform this code in the constructor. How to make this code worked?

```
protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (AutoSize_)
    {
        this.AutoSize = true;
        remember_size = this.Size;
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.Size = new Size(remember_size.Width, remember_size.Height);
        remember_size = this.Size;
    }
        ...
        this.Invalidate();
 }
```

But don't work. For example this code work:

```
 protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (AutoSize_)
    {
        this.AutoSize = true;
    }
           ...
          this.Invalidate();
 }
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @cguedel To get to the designer to change the size of MyLabel on Form.

Comment: The Label control already implements all this.  It is unclear why you are trying to reinvent that wheel, just inherit your control from Label instead of Control.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to resize the label so the text is visible, regardless of the font size, the **AutoSize** property will do this for you.. However if you for some reason wish to handle this with your own code, you could try setting the AutoSize property to false (and not change it..)

Answer (score 0):

The following code method can be called from any Form, UserControl, or Control.  It will return the size of the specified text in the specified font.

```
public static Size MeasureText(Graphics graphicsDevice, String text, Font font)
{
    System.Drawing.SizeF textSize = graphicsDevice.MeasureString(text, font);
    int width = (int)Math.Ceiling(textSize.Width);
    int heigth = (int)Math.Ceiling(textSize.Height);

    Size size = new Size(width, heigth);
    return size;
}
```

Now you will need to check that the label has not outgrown the parent container, which would cause some of the labels text to be cut off.  Something like the following will accomplish this:

```
        private void ResizeParentAccordingToLabelSize(Label resizedLabel)
    {
        int necessaryWidth = resizedLabel.Location.X + resizedLabel.Width;
        int necessaryHeight = resizedLabel.Location.Y + resizedLabel.Height;

        if (necessaryWidth > this.Width)
        {
            this.Width = necessaryWidth;
        }

        if (necessaryHeight > this.Height)
        {
            this.Height = necessaryHeight;
        }
    }
```